# Synchronous Json calls from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

I'm working on a project where inside a loop I need to make multiple JSON calls.  As soon as I exit that loop I need to work with the results of all the calls I made.  I'm having a hard time understanding how to make these calls in such a way that my order of operation works out.  My code to work with the results always executes before the calls to the service have completed.  I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate and am including the code here.

http://jsfiddle.net/VEkrf/3/

```
    var sourceData = { "fooIndex": "foo",
        "barIndex": "bar"
    }
    var destinationData = {};
    for (var sourceIndex in sourceData) {
        $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/' + sourceIndex + '/' + sourceData[sourceIndex] + '?callback=?', null, function (result) {
            for (var resultIndex in result) {
                alert("Adding " + resultIndex + " : " + result[resultIndex]);
                destinationData[resultIndex] = result[resultIndex];
            }
        });
    }

    if (Object.keys(destinationData).length == 0) {
        alert("Destination not yet populated");
    }
    else {
        alert("Eureka!  You did it!");
    }
```

Comment: Don't use synchronous AJAX. It's extremely slow, especially when you make several ones. Instead count the number of requests finished and do something on the last one.

Comment: In my case the service I'm working with can only process 10 records at a time.  I'm taking groups of 100+ records, regrouping then in groups of 10 and sending the requests out.  When I get the responses I need to know was it the first, second or third request so I can match the results to the source data.  The service has no way of sending along a key so I can match the result back to it's original record.  I can't think of any better way to approach this than synchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a job for [jQuery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and my sidekick [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)!

Pass all the `$.getJSON` calls to `$.when`, and when they are all done, I'll will call a function with *all* the results.

Check this out:

```
var sourceData = {
    "fooIndex": "foo",
    "barIndex": "bar"
};
var destinationData = {};

// Array of AJAX calls
var AJAX = [];

for (var sourceIndex in sourceData) {
    AJAX.push($.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/' + sourceIndex + '/' + sourceData[sourceIndex] + '?callback=?'));
}

// Apply is needed to pass each element as a parameter
$.when.apply($, AJAX).done(function(){
    // This function will be called when all the AJAX calls are done

    // The arguments of the functin are the responses from each request
    for(var i = 0, len = AJAX.length; i < len; i++){
        var result = arguments[i][0];
        //arguments: [resultObj, 'success', jqXHR]
        for (var resultIndex in result) {
            alert("Adding " + resultIndex + " : " + result[resultIndex]);
            destinationData[resultIndex] = result[resultIndex];
        }
    }

    alert("Eureka!  You did it!");
});
```

NOTE: Since this is asynchronous, `destinationData` won't be available until the callback is triggered.  Put any code that uses that *inside* the `.done()` callback.

Comment: I have read a lot about differed but I have never been able to successfully implement it. This is a nice example.

Comment: @Pow-Ian: When I first saw it, I was struggling with it too.  It's not too bad once you get to know it.

Comment: I have been meaning to take a second look. I realize it does make a lot more sense pragmatically than queue for things like this.

Comment: @Pow-Ian: It can be a bit confusing.  All AJAX methods in jQuery now return "promise" objects.  Those promises have a `.done()` method, that is called when it's done.  Promises can be combined with `$.when()` which itself returns promise (which has a `.done()` method).  You can also create your own promise objects with `var d = new $.Deferred`, and call the `d.resolveWith()` method on that new deferred once you're done.

Comment: Will this solution guarantee that the requests are processed in the order they were sent?  The reason I was looking to process syncronously is because I'm going to need a way to identify if the response is returned from the first, second, third call etc...  I've got 100 + records that I am submitting to the service in batches of 10.  When I receive the response I need to know if it was the second request because then I know the first record will match with the 11th record from my larger collection.

Comment: @Troy: Yes, it will.  :-) The arguments in the `done()` method will be in the same order as how they are passed to `$.when` (meaning `arguments[1]` will be the 2nd AJAX request).  Here's an example, notice the order of the `alert`s compared to the order of `sourceData`: http://jsfiddle.net/Sb7PC/

Comment: One of the biggest reasons why I have not used this yet is because I do not always know ahead of time how many ajax requests I need. I use the queue to manage all my ajax calls on an ajax intensive page I have. In that case I would be using the deferred just like a queue. So I think I will stick with my queue. But really great example. Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using jQuery already I suggest exploring the queue functions. You can queue the ajax calls and then in the success handlers call the de-queue or next function. this way they go in succession. The last item you add to the queue is your function that handles the returned data.

```
var sourceData = {
    "fooIndex": "foo",
    "barIndex": "bar"
};
var destinationData = {};

$(function () {
    console.debug('ready');
    for (var sourceIndex in sourceData) {
        console.debug('for Loop');
        $(document).queue('ajax', function (next) {
            $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/' + sourceIndex + '/' + sourceData[sourceIndex] + '?callback=?', null, function (result) {
                for (var resultIndex in result) {
                    alert("Adding " + resultIndex + " : " + result[resultIndex]);
                    destinationData[resultIndex] = result[resultIndex];
                    next();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).queue('ajax', function (next) {
        alert("Eureka!  You did it!");
    });
    $(document).dequeue('ajax');
});
```

I do this all the time for 'synchronus' ajax.

[here is an example of what i am talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/EheyN/4/)

Comment: Before I learned how to use jQuery Deferred, this would be the method I would use. :-)

Comment: Same thing I normally did, until I took the time to learn deferred (feels almost like using [`caolan/async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) in node); when you have a static "queue" of things to send. For a dynamic "queue" of calls I generally will use `$().queue` still.

Comment: but what if your success and error handlers are not static? How would you do that with deferred? would you be able to assign multiple done handlers or would you have to pass your success functions into deferred? Does jQuery execute all the procedures at once and only trigger 'done' when they all complete? In that case what happens when the second function passed to deferred requires information that is only available after the first function has completed?

Comment: @Pow-Ian: Pretty sure deferreds run all the functions at the same time, and then calls `.done` when they are all finished.  If you need info from one function in the other, then the queue might be your method.

Comment: I'm not really sure which is a "better" solution based on the discussions.  Yours worked too in fiddle, but I ended up implementing Hazmat's.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hazmat's is better since you have one done handler.Use the queue method when you have multiple Ajax calls that depend on each other. I have no choice but to wait and execute them in order. Also my handlers are different for each function. Since you have one handler and you are getting multiple similar calls, it makes a hell of a lot more sense to shoot them all off at once and then collect the results after they have all completed. The only down side I can see is that you must wait for them all to complete. With a queue you can act on the return while waiting for the rest to complete.

Comment: I can't edit my comment but I meant to say, 'before' instead of 'while' waiting for the rest of the calls to complete.